# iOS: Deleting Test Flight builds in App Store Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Before ever submitting, I uploaded a build of an app to App Store Connect to have beta testers try it on Test Flight, and it's version 1.0.0.  I then had a few more testers try some fixes in a version 1.0.1.  Is there anyway I can 'remove' these version so that I can submit a `1.0.0` to the App Store as my first App store build rather than having the first submission of an app be 1.0.1?

Comment: You can't remove them, but as long as you have a higher build number on your new 1.0.0 upload it won't matter; you can select that new build in AppStore connect and submit it for review. The 1.0.1 builds won't even be visible until you create a 1.0.1 AppStore release

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks!  My issue is though that I don't want my first AppStore release to be 1.0.1.  Ideally, it'd be 1.0.0 but the 1.0.0 version I uploaded and had people try out in Test Flight needed a lot of bug fixes.  So in my case,  there's no way to release a 1.0.0 for the AppStore then right?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Your AppStore build and your TestFlight builds are separate.  Make sure that the version number in your AppStore information in AppStore connect is 1.0.0, upload a build with that version and a higher build number than any previous 1.0.0 build and select the new build in App Store Connect.  However, to be honest the version number doesn't really matter.  Sooner or later you will release a 1.1 or whatever and new users will just see that in the App Store (If they even look at the version number, which they probably won't)

Comment: gotcha, thanks a lot for explaining this to me @Paulw11!